# C# From user input to vector with class object

Tags: c#, class

Okey. so I created a class in a seperate file that looks like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


class City
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int temp { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to set values (from user input) in each element of this new vector.

```
City[] Cities = new City[4];
for (int i = 0; i < Cities.Length; i++)
{    
            
    Console.Write("Name of city:");
    Cities[i].name = Console.ReadLine();


    Console.Write("Temperature:");
    string strTemp = Console.ReadLine();
    Cities[i].temp = Convert.ToInt32(strTemp); 
}
```

but when I reach:

```
Cities[i].name = Console.ReadLine();
```

I get this messege:

***Unhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.***

Comment: Welcome to SO. What's the definition of the class `City`? And what line of your code is throwing the exception?

Comment: Based on the code you've shown us, neither do we. Can we get a [mcve]?

Comment: class City
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int temp { get; set; }
}

This is how class City looks like.

Comment: @JerryOhlson - Please edit your question instead of putting code in the comments. Also, you will need to show a [mcve] as the class and the code in your question doesn't give you that.

Comment: If you used the term "vector" because you are comming from C++, then think of it this way: this is *not* a vector of cities. It is an array of references to cities, none of them initialized with any city yet.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `new City[4];` isn't enough to instantiate each instance in the array. It simply creates an empty, or `null`, element in the array. You still have to instantiate the instance.

Try this:

```
City[] Cities = new City[4];
for (int i = 0; i < Cities.Length; i++)
{
    Cities[i] = new City();
    
    Console.Write("Name of city:");
    Cities[i].name = Console.ReadLine();


    Console.Write("Temperature:");
    string strTemp = Console.ReadLine();
    Cities[i].temp = Convert.ToInt32(strTemp);
}
```

Comment: No worries. Don't forget to upvote and accept.